# Problem Updating MESA

Tags: graphics

I tried to upgrade the mesa package using the ppa ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers.

But there comes this error message while upgrading essential packages

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gnome-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed

I tried sudo apt-get install libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7, but it says its already the latest version and the version numbers satisfy the error

I don't know what to do about this problem.

Answer (score 1):

freya 0.3.2 uses ubuntu lts 14.04.2 as base and the ppa ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers don't support that ubuntu version, thats why is showing you those errors